# How to descript state transform in JavaDoc comment

Tags: javadoc

I defined a state Enum.I want to show the transform process between states in Java comment. How can I do it? Can you give me a comment template?

Answer (score 0):

What does "transform proceess" mean?
Is this right?

```
/**
 * Define enum
 */
public enum MyEnum{
            SUCCESS;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    function();
}

/**
 *This is xxxx function.
 * @return {@link MainActivity.MyEnum#SUCCESS}:Return Success.
 */
public int function(){
    return MyEnum.SUCCESS.ordinal();
}
```